Locally change the list environment that org mode exports to
I need some lists to be normal lists (latex \enumerate) and some to be inline (latex \enumerate*) from the enumitem package.
Is there something like #+ATTR_LATEX I can give to make \enumerate change to \enumerate* on some lists?

Yes, there is:
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

* Lists

- one

- two

- three

and an enumerated list:

1. four

2. five

3. six



and an enumerate* list:
#+ATTR_LATEX: :environment enumerate*
1. seven

2. eight

3. nine

The documentation is not explicit enough here (the :environment setting is described in the section about exporting tables in LaTeX), but it works for anything, not just tables. EDIT: As the OP points out in a comment, there is an example in the Plain lists in LaTeX export section, which I missed.

Tnx (as always!) Nick. To be fair its there in section 13.10.7 (plain lists in Latex export). Sure it could be more findable and structured than it is now. But frankly I know too little Latex to know what to search!

I stand corrected - thanks!
